# Why do I need to reboot mac to activate HDMI device sound?

Tags: audio

MacBook Air, Retina, 13-inch, 2019
Running Big Sur

Using USB-C to HDMI adaptors, many of them, MacBook Air sound preference center cannot recognize the device it is plugged to (HDMI cable connects the adaptor to the TV monitor; sound on TV monitors has been tested)

Video is fine

Troubleshoot this on two different screens, and two different projectors (hooked to speakers)

Troubleshoot while being powered on (i.e. with AC plugged in)
No sound nor device detected (in the sound panel) in every case.

In each case, the sound is being played through the MacBook Air internal speakers.

I need to reboot the laptop and some times turn off the laptop and then turn on in order to start working.

I've already tried to stop and start audio drivers but that doesn't work.  Is there a command to restart usb-c drivers on mac or any other command to restore the detection of the device without rebooting?

Comment: Which adapters are you using? After _years_ of dealing with adapters to attach to classroom AV systems, Belkin and Anker branded adapters have proven to be the most reliable. For several years, we had MDP > HDMI adapters, but when Apple switched to USBC, we needed another adapter. Now we use an Anker USBC hub to connect to the projector through HDMI, and USBA for external mics and interactive control on the projector, as well as providing power to the laptop. _Note: no financial or other connection to Anker or Belkin_

Comment: I've had the sound problem before with windows to tv over hdmi.  In my case often unplugging the hdmi and plugging it back it would cause the hdmi handshake to occur and the sound would come out the tv.  I've mostly switched to having my video files on a share and having a firestick with VLC play the video files.